# What's the limit of a recursive superset operation called?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

> What's the limit of a recursive superset operation called?

I'm tentatively thinking it's a colimit or an inverse limit but I don't know the correct terminology.

For example:

let $X=2\Bbb N-1$, i.e. the odd, positive integers.

Let $f(X)=\{1,2\}\cdot X$

Where the dot product is defined as $X\cdot Y=\{xy:x\in X, y\in Y\}$, i.e. the union of the products of every pair of elements drawn one from each set.

Then we have $f^{n-1}(X)\subsetneq f^{n}(X)$ and furthermore in this example $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(X)=\Bbb N$

where $n$ indicates the number of compositions of $f$.

---

Surely there is some terminology for this type of limit?

Comment: It might be worth defining your terms more precisely. Is $2\mathbb{N}-1$ the set of positive odd numbers? What does $\{ 1, 2 \} \cdot X$ mean? And what does $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}$ mean when the thing you're taking a limit of is a set?

Comment: I'll add that I suspect that the concept you are looking for is a colimit (= direct limit) of a chain of inclusions $X \hookrightarrow f(X) \hookrightarrow f^2(X) \hookrightarrow f^3(X) \hookrightarrow \cdots$, which in the category of sets is simply the union $\bigcup_{n \ge 0} f^n(X)$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead yes that looks like exactly it. I think I've added all necessary clarifications to the question.  Does that now define a colimit and should I be using the squiggly arrow?  I just want the right notation for here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848468/ to eliminate any possible confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you're just talking about the union: $\mathbb N=\bigcup_n f^n(X)$.

However, this can also be thought of as a *supremum*, $\mathbb N = \sup_n f^n(X)$, since indeed, in the partially ordered set $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, $\mathbb N$ is the least upper bound of the family $(f^n(X))_n$. In measure theory, you often see the terminology:

$$\limsup_n A_n=\bigcap_{k\geq n}\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right)$$
$$\liminf_n A_n=\bigcup_{k\geq n}\left(\bigcap_n A_n\right)$$

which are just the direct transpositions of the usual definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ from the poset $\mathbb R$ to the poset $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$. Notice that these two sets have nice set-theoretic interpretations: the $\limsup$ is the set of points that are in infinitely many of the $A_i$, and the $\liminf$ is the set of points that are in all of the $A_i$ past a certain point. If these two sets are equal, then nothing is stopping you from calling that common value $\lim A_n$, of course, and in your case we will indeed have $\lim f^n(X)=\mathbb N$, as you can check yourself. This is due to a proposition which should reinforce the analogy with limits in $\mathbb R$ even further:

> If $A_n$ is an increasing (with respect to inclusion) sequence of sets, then it always has a limit and $\lim A_n=\sup A_n=\bigcup A_n$.

The reason for this analogy between the "topology" of $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ (for some set $\Omega$) and $\mathbb R$ is because, like $\mathbb R$, the poset $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ is a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) satisfying the crucial *least upper bound property*.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware it is also the union but it's specifically the $\sup$ I wanted as (and my intuition may be way off here, but) it seems likely it will be simpler to get to a good understanding of the properties of such a set by thinking of some single, limiting set, perhaps in a metric space scenario, rather than the union of infinitely many sets.